# How to combine two base plots in R?

Tags: r, plot

```
my.date <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-10-14 00:00:00", format="%F %T"), 
               by="hour", 
               length.out=6*128*24)  

library('WaveletComp')
x <- periodic.series(start.period=1*24, length=6*128*24)
my.data <- data.frame(date=my.date, x=x)

my.wt <- analyze.wavelet(my.data, "x",                   
                         loess.span=0, 
                         dt=1/24, dj=1/20, 
                         lowerPeriod=1/4, 
                         make.pval=TRUE, n.sim=10)


layaout2 <- layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3), nrow=3))
wt.image(my.wt, main="wavelet power spectrum",
         legend.params=list(lab="wavelet power levels (quantiles)", 
                              lab.line=3.5, 
                              label.digits=2),
         periodlab="period (days)")
p1 <- recordPlot() 
wt.image(my.wt, main="wavelet power spectrum",
         legend.params=list(lab="wavelet power levels (quantiles)", 
                              lab.line=3.5, 
                              label.digits=2),
         periodlab="period (days)")
p2 <- recordPlot()
plot_grid(p1, p2,
          labels='AUTO',
          hjust=0, vjust=1)
```

I got error

```
Error in if (labels) { : missing value where TRUE / FALSE is required
```

Comment: With your code, i get an error at the first `wt.image()` about the `figure margins being too large`

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover That's because _your_ RStudio preview window is not set large enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can't place `"recordedplot"` objects on a `layout`.

Not sure why you want use `grDevices::recordPlot` at all, maybe you want to mimick some sort of ggplot behavior. However, base `plot`, or `WaveletComp::wt.image` which uses it, will always complete plotting, so you would always see your plots twice.

So you may stick with `layout` or use `par(mfrow=)` as in *@robert-hacken*'s answer, and set `graphics.reset=FALSE` according to his advice.

I recommend using the `png` device rather than RStudio preview window; it's much faster and produces hard-coded image size. Plot is stored in working directory (or use `png('/<path>/foo.R')`). If you don't want use it, just comment out `png` and `dev.off` line:

```
png('foo.png', 800, 600)  ## open png device

layout(matrix(c(1, 2), nrow=2))
par(mar=c(3, 3, 3, 3) + .6)  ## slightly reduce margins
wt.image(my.wt, main="wavelet power spectrum",
         legend.params=list(lab="wavelet power levels (quantiles)", 
                            lab.line=3.5, 
                            label.digits=2),
         periodlab="period (days)",
         graphics.reset=FALSE)
wt.image(my.wt, main="wavelet power spectrum",
         legend.params=list(lab="wavelet power levels (quantiles)", 
                            lab.line=3.5, 
                            label.digits=2),
         periodlab="period (days)",
         graphics.reset=FALSE)

dev.off()  ## close png device
```

[image]

*Note:* Don't use `layout` together w/ `par(mfrow=, mfcol=)` options, as they are not compatible.

### Update

To combine multiple analyses in a plot, store first analyses in a `list`, then loop over the list to plot. *Example:*

```
my.data3 <- my.data2 <- my.data1 <- my.data

my.wt_lst <- Map(
  analyze.wavelet,
  my.data=list(my.data1, my.data2, my.data3),
  my.serie='x',
  loess.span=c(0, .25, .5),
  dt=1/24,
  dj=1/20,
  lowerPeriod=1/4,
  make.pval=TRUE,
  n.sim=10
)
```

`Map` loops over elements synchronously, i.e. if there's just one as in `dt=1/24` it will always use `1/24`, if there's multiple as in `my.data=list(my.data1, my.data2, my.data3)`, or `loess.span=c(0, .25, .5)`, it will use the elements one by one. Note, that a list or data.frame itself is a list w/ multiple elements, and you'd need to list it again, e.g. `my.data=list(my.data1)` instead of just `my.data=my.data1`.

```
png('foo.png', 1200, 600)
layout(matrix(seq_along(my.wt_lst), nrow=length(my.wt_lst)))
par(mar=c(3, 3, 3, 3) + .6)  ## slightly reduce margins
for (i in seq_along(my.wt_lst)) {
  wt.image(my.wt_lst[[i]], main="wavelet power spectrum",
           legend.params=list(lab="wavelet power levels (quantiles)", 
                              lab.line=3.5, 
                              label.digits=2),
           periodlab="period (days)",
           graphics.reset=FALSE)
}
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, can I save the plots in a list? because i want to loop thru several cases and save a plot for each csae. finally i save all to foo.png in one page.

Comment: @temor List the analysis, then loop over the list to plot results. See update.

Comment: last question, please, can we reduce the white areas between the panels?

Comment: @temor Specify what you mean by "white areas between the panels".

Comment: the areas between index and wavelet power spectrum

Comment: the spaces in factes

Comment: @temor Space between plot and legend?!

Comment: yes, and space between the first panel and the second and between the second and the third

Comment: @temor  Space between plot and legend apparently not implemented, you could hack the `wt.image` function. For the latter, play with the `par`, e.g. `par(mar=c(2, 3, 3, 3) + .6`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard base R methods, e.g. `par(mfrow=c(2, 1))`. Just make sure to set `graphics.reset=F` for `wt.image()` as otherwise it will reset the original graphical parameters when finishing, which notably reapplies the `mfrow` setting and the next plot will be put on a new page.

```r
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
wt.image(my.wt, main = "wavelet power spectrum",
         legend.params = list(lab = "wavelet power levels (quantiles)", 
                              lab.line = 3.5, 
                              label.digits = 2),
         periodlab = "period (days)",
         graphics.reset=F)
wt.image(my.wt, main = "wavelet power spectrum",
         legend.params = list(lab = "wavelet power levels (quantiles)", 
                              lab.line = 3.5, 
                              label.digits = 2),
         periodlab = "period (days)",
         graphics.reset=F)
```

[image: two plots]

Comment: Nice spot the `graphics.reset=FALSE` +1